# Count matches in the previous 100 rows

Tags: mysql

As the title states, I'm trying to count the number of matches within the last 100 records in a certain table.

This query works, but the data is very dynamic, with lots of inserts on that particular table, and similar queries are being run, and they all end up being extremely slow (20s) probably blocking each other out.

Because caching the result is not acceptable (data has to be live) I'm thinking of switching the exterior query to a PHP, even though I know that would be slower because it would still be faster than 20s.

Here's the query

```
SELECT count(*) as matches
FROM (
  SELECT first_name FROM customers
  WHERE division = 'some_division'
  AND type = 'employee'
  ORDER BY request_time DESC
  LIMIT 0, 100
) as entries
WHERE first_name = 'some_first_name_here'
```

What I'm looking for a more optimized way of performing the same task, without having to implement it in PHP since that's the naive/obviously wrong approach.

the table looks something like this:

```
id first_name last_name type division request_time
```

Just to set things straight, this is obviously not the actual table / data due to NDA reasons, but, the table looks exactly the same with different column names.

So again, what I'm trying to achieve is to pull a count of matches found WITHIN the last 100 records which have some contraints.

for example,

```
how many times does the name 'John' appear within the last 100 employees added in the HR division?
```

Comment: Get rid of the wrapper, and add that last WHERE condition to the others. The number of rows returned will tell you the count. A compound index on (division,type,first_name) would, I presume, also help.

Comment: In the internal query you select only the `user_id`, but then you filter the results on a different column (`first_name`). Is this really possible?! Are you sure this query works??? In addition, can you please write the schema of the table?

Comment: @Strawberry that would only give me the count within the entire table, and I need it within the last 100 entries. A compound index however is a good suggestion and it may improve this entire thing.

Comment: @winterlude when renaming stuff around to avoid any sort of NDA issues I missnamed it. should be good now.

Comment: I agree that an index (maybe only for column `first_name`) will surely help. I suggest reading this post: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: @winterlude first_name is already indexed

Comment: Is there an auto_increment column on the table? In the mean time, try a "covering" index on (division, type, request time, first_name), except remove any with low cardinality.

Comment: @MarcusAdams there is an auto_increment on the id column, could you please explain the term low cardinality?

Answer (score 0):

I see.

How about something like this...

```
 SELECT i 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT CASE WHEN first_name = 'some_first_name_here' THEN @i:=@i+1 END i 
          FROM customers
         WHERE division = 'some_division'
           AND type = 'employee'
             , (SELECT @i:=0)val  
         ORDER 
            BY request_time 
          DESC        
         LIMIT 0,100
      ) n 
  ORDER 
     BY i DESC 
  LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(matches)
FROM
(
    SELECT IF(first_name = 'some_first_name_here', 1, 0) AS matches
    FROM customers
    WHERE division = 'some_division' AND type = 'employee'
    ORDER BY request_time DESC
    LIMIT 0,100
) AS entries
```